# Scanning BLE periperal: "hcitool lesan" does not work

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to scan my BLE peripheral from my Linux box. I did:

```
sudo hictool -i hci0 lescan.
```

but it reported: Set scan parameters failed. Input/Output error.

The Ubuntu is 19.10.  What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list all` and `sudo hcitool dev` to the question.

Comment: rfkill list all comand result:
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo hcitool dev result:

Devices:
    hci0    AB:CD:38:DB:13:58